# Возникла ошибка в Postman после запроса

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas

возникла ошибка "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoices.0' in 'field list' in /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:212\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-db/src/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php(212): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 /var/www/src/App/src/Service/DebitCreditClientsService.php(59): Laminas\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement->execute()\n#2 /var/www/src/App/src/Handler/DebitCreditClientsHandler.php(35): App\Service\DebitCreditClientsService->get('2023-01-02:2023...', false, 0, 0)\n#3 /var/www/vendor/laminas/laminas-stratigility/src/Middleware/RequestHandlerMiddleware.php(46): App\Handler\DebitCreditClientsHandler->handle(Object(Laminas\Diactoros\ServerRequest))\n#4 /var/www/vendor/mezzio/mezzio/src/Middleware/LazyLoadingMiddleware.php(26): Laminas\Stratigility\Middleware\RequestHandlerMiddleware-

```
 function get($period = '', $isIncludingTax = true)
{   
    if ($period == '') {                  
        $period = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", strtotime("-11 month")), 1, date("Y", strtotime("-11 month"))))
                  . ':' .
                  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("t"), date("Y")));                    
    }

    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);

    $select = $sql->select($this->_dbPrefix . 'invoices', $this->adapter);

    $select->columns([
        'invoice_type'          => new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression("'invoices'"),
        'data',
        'invoice_id'            => 'id',
        'invoice_number'        => new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('CONCAT(idu_pref, idu)'),
        'id',
        'data_pay',
        'amount_paid',
        'payed',
        'paymentdate',
        'total_count'           => new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('COUNT(*)'),
        'total_incoming_amount' => 0,
        'total_invoice_amount'  => new \Laminas\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('SUM(calc_total_excl)'),
    ]);

    $result = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select)->execute();

    $result = [
        [
            "name"        => "Invoices",
            "values"      => $this->getInvoiceData($isIncludingTax, $period),
            "type"        => "invoices",
            "translation" => $this->translateService->translate('Invoices'),
        ],
        [
            "name"        => "Incoming",
            "values"      => $this->getIncomingInvoiceData($isIncludingTax, $period),
            "type"        => "incoming",
            "translation" => $this->translateService->translate('Incoming'),
        ],
        [
            'name'        => 'Contacts',
            'values'      => $this->getContacts($isIncludingTax, $period),
            'type'        => 'contacts',
            'translation' => $this->translateService->translate('Contacts'),
        ],
    ];

    return $result;
}
```